# Tapping into fade events for Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Many transitions in Bootstrap 4 provide a set of events to listen for. For example, you could do something like:

```
$('.certainDropdowns').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function() {
  // do the things
});
```

A light inspection of some of the components shows that somehow they are able to respond to fading. For example, the Bootstrap modal fires a "hidden" event once it has faded out. But this is at the modal level, not the transition level (`hidden.bs.modal`)

Unlike dropdowns and modals, there is not a "fade" JavaScript component. But the light scan of the source code seems to be indicating that Bootstrap provides emulation for CSS transitionEvent, and I'm trying to figure out how I can tap into it.

**In brief:**

Is there a Bootstrap 4-provided method for tapping into the fade transition's events, or am I limited to native `transitionend` (possibly with help from a 3rd-party polyfill)?

**[edit to add content below]**

I possibly should have tried `transitionend` before posting the question, but I just gave it a try and it seems to be no go like this:

```
<div id="something" class="fade show">Fadeable</div>
```

Then JS:

```
$('#something').on('transitionend', function() {
  console.log('transition ended!');
});

//later
$('#something').removeClass('show');
```

This was tested only with the latest Firefox, which is one of my target browsers.

Comment: `transitionend`

Comment: @PraveenKumar, just gave it a go (brief updated code now in question) and the way I used it didn't seem to work. Granted, first time I ever tried `transitionend`, so maybe I misunderstand how it's supposed to work.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to tap in to? As far as I can tell BS4 components that allow such hooks are defined for each component.

Comment: Without using jQuery.animate (because I am still targeting the slim version), I wanted to chain animations. I wanted to fade out and THEN collapse. I ended up writing a different solution, which I will provide as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it in my intended way with the provided components. Instead, I ended up writing it as a single new class, "collapseFade" which could still use the Bootstrap pattern of adding/removing the class "show".

The tricky thing was that transitions would trample over each other if I just tried to add or remove the "show" class, so I had to add a second helper class, "out". This requires intimate understanding of the new classes, which was potentially hazardous to maintenance developers. Consequently, I wrote a jQuery plugin to go with it. Without using this answer as code repository, here's the lightweight breakdown:

SASS:

```
.collapseFade {
    max-height: 400px; 
    transition:
        max-height 0.5s,
        opacity 0.5s 0.5s;

    &:not(.show) {
        opacity: 0;
        max-height: 0;
    }
}

.collapseFade.out {
    transition:
        max-height 0.5s 0.5s,
        opacity 0.5s;

    &:not(.show) {
        opacity: 0;
        max-height: 0;
    }
}
```

(You could theoretically use Bootstrap's SASS fade variables instead of hard-coding time intervals).

Then the plug-in (code not included, for brevity) simply allows you to call `collapseFade` on an element. Eg. `$('.something').collapseFade()`. It optionally accepts "show" or "hide" as string parameters, but will just toggle by default. For whatever reason, `transitionend` is working here, so I also listen and fire an appropriate custom event for future maintenance or feature devs who might find it useful.

It functions thus: when showing, it removes the `out` class and adds the `show` class. When hiding, it adds the `out` class and then removes the `show` class.

The so-called "magic" is just in the timing. The second transition start is delayed by a value equal to the first transition time, which visually chains them together even though technically they are fired at the same time.

The other tricky bit is that the collapse animates `max-height` rather than `height`. This is the way Bootstrap themselves do it, and it makes sense... you can't animate "auto" height; it needs an actual target number. But straight-up "height" (no "max") means you're committed to occupying a certain amount of space. Max-height will allow height to be dynamic, but the trade-off is that it will operate smoothly only by restricting it as closely as possible. If I had put max-height of ten-thousand, for example, the collapsing animation wouldn't be smooth. You might notice that in Bootstrap's own collapse functionality, which is less than smooth for elements that are not tall. I don't anticipate my targets to be any taller than 400px so that's what I've provided.